# Regular expression in java for deleting dot sign (.) and the char before it

Tags: java, regex

I have to create a program in java that reads a string from the user which contains dot (.) sign on it. I need to delete the dot and the char before it, and print the result.

So if the input is : `mx.erw.ho.abe.a`

It should print : `merhaba`

Or if the input is : `lok.okl. u.ay.t t.tho.p.e e.sku.y`

It should print : `look at the sky`

This is what i have done so far, which kind of works but it cuts out even the last letter of the word (if it is `merhaba`, this code prints `merhab` and if it is `look at the sky`, it prints `look at the sk`

How can i fix this?

```
public class HiddenMessage {
    
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        
        String [] message="lok.okl. u.ay.t t.tho.p.e e.sku.y".split("[.]");
        
            for(int i=0;i<message.length;i++) {
                
                    System.out.print(message[i].substring(0, message[i].length()-1));
            }
        
    
    }
}
```

---

Update:

So now my code looks like this if i want to take the input from the user. It prints `merhaba` just fine but it only prints `"look"` not `"look from the sky"`

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class HiddenMessage {
    
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        
        Scanner input=new Scanner (System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Please enter the message: ");
        
        String message=input.next();
        
        String m1=message.replaceAll("\\w\\*", "");
        
        System.out.print(m1);
            
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `replaceAll()` method and the regex `\\w\\.`

Try this:

```
String result = "lok.okl. u.ay.t t.tho.p.e e.sku.y".replaceAll("\\w\\.", "");
```

- `\\w` : matches a word character (Letter, digit, underscore)
- `\\.` : matches dot character

If you use the regex `".\\."` it literally matches the dot and the char before it.

- `.` : matches any character

---

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter the message: ");

String message = input.nextLine();

String m1 = message.replaceAll("\\w\\.", "");

System.out.print(m1);
```

Comment: *"and the char before it"* — shouldn't `\\w` be `.` instead?

Comment: @MCEmperor yes, i thought about word character but you're right, gonna add an update..

Comment: What if I want to read the string from the user? Because it works fine with the code you sent but when i tried it by reading it from the user, it only prints "look"

Comment: @Leticia please update the code with the part you take the input from the user so that i can help you.

Comment: yes i just updated it. Btw the second method you showed, whit the . instead of \\w, doesnt work, so im going with the \\w since it is fine

Comment: @Leticia you're using `\\*` instead of `\\.` and `nextLine()` will help you to read the whole line. adding the update...